# Finding Nested value(s) within nested values in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following code with the intention of locating values from within a targeted div as follows:

```
$('#combineDiv').children().each(function(){
      if ($(this + ":first-child").attr('class') == 'combinedColumn') {
          alert('found ONE!');
     }
 });
```

I have a hidden input in some of the divs within the children of the div '#combineDiv'... but, I dont know how to combine the 'THIS' keyword with the appropriate selector... :(

Comment: Use `.filter("selectors")`,i.e. `$(this).filter(":first-child")....`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remember `this` is going to return an object from the DOM, so `$(this + ":first-child")` probably isn't going to give you what you want (it'll probably return something like [object Object]:first-child.

Instead try accessing the ID, or whatever it is you're after, off of that `this` object

$(this.ID + ":first-child").attr('class')

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).filter(":first-child")
```

Comment: I thought this would work -- here is my html: <div style="border: 1px solid; background-color: lightyellow; display: block;" class="column" id="col0"><input type="hidden" value="FormRecordID" id="hiddenCol#col0" class="combinedColumn">FormRecordID</div>

NOW I created that div with a CLICK event that inserts that hidden input into that div .... but when I try and do something like this ---
 alert($(this).filter(":first-child").val());  - It always comes back undefined...?
---

Comment: i think the problem is you doing a `children().each` and then a `:first-child`.  Why don't you try putting all you HTML in the question then we can see from #combineDiv down

Comment: This will probably make some of you wince, but I just took the easy way out and did a couple loops to get my value:
  $('#combineDivInner').children().each(function(){
        //If it is a column (div) then get the hidden value out of it.
        if ($(this).attr('class') == 'column') {
               colCount++;
               $(this).children().each(function() {
                       if ($(this).attr('class') == 'columnHiddenVal') {                                           formulaString += $(this).val();}});                            
                        }

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're trying to do, but my assumption is that you want to look inside each child of the `#combineDiv` for a `:first-child`, that is a `.combinedColumn`

```
$("#combineDiv > * > .combinedColumn:first-child");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.filter("selectors")`,i.e. `$(this).filter(":first-child")....`

In fact you could use `$(this).filter(":first-child .combinedColumn")` I believe.

Answer (score 0):

use .find to travel more than one level down

```
$('#combineDiv').find(selector).each(
              function(){
                if ($(this + ":first-child").attr('class') == 'combinedColumn') {
                                   alert('found ONE!');
                            }
                        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `has` method to get the elements that has children that matches a selector, intead of looping through the children yourself:

```
$('#combineDiv').children().has('.combinedColumn:first-child').each(function(){
  alert('found ONE!');
});
```

Example:

With this HTML:

```
<div id ="combineDiv">
  <div><span class="none">1</span><span class="none">1</span></div>
  <div><span class="none">2</span><span class="combinedColumn">2</span></div>
  <div><span class="combinedColumn">3</span><span class="none">3</span></div>
  <div><span class="combinedColumn">4</span><span class="combinedColumn">4</span></div>
</div>
```

This will match the third and fourth child div and make their background gray, as they have a first child with the class "combinedColumn":

```
$('#combineDiv').children().has('.combinedColumn:first-child').css('background', '#ccc');
```